# discord.js "Unknown Interaction Exception" and "has not been sent or preferred Exception" occurred despite the use of interaction#deferredReply()

Tags: discord, discord.js

```js
    async execute(interaction) {
        interaction.deferReply();
        
        let name_tag = interaction.options.getString('검색어');
        if (name_tag === '*'){
            name_tag = '';
        }

        const result = await request(`https://api.the-finals-leaderboard.com/v1/leaderboard/s2/crossplay?name=${name_tag}`)
        const rank_data= await result.body.json()

        const page_length = rank_data.count;

        if (page_length === 0) {
            interaction.editReply("검색 결과가 없습니다 (ㅠ ㅠ)");
            return;
        }

        let now_page = 0;
        let data = rank_data.data[now_page]

        const response = await interaction.editReply({
            embeds: [createEmbed(data)],
            components: [createPageButton(data, now_page, page_length)],
        });

        const collector = response.createMessageComponentCollector({
            fillter: i => i.user.id === interaction.user.id,
            componentType: ComponentType.Button, 
            idle: 20_000
        });

        collector.on('collect', async i => {
            const component = i.component;

            now_page += Number(component.customId.replaceAll('page_count_', ""));
            data = rank_data.data[now_page]
            
            await i.update({
                embeds: [createEmbed(data)],
                components: [createPageButton(data, now_page, page_length)],
            });

        });

        collector.on('end', async () => {
            response.edit({ components: []})
        })
    }
```

I don't get errors every time, but sometimes. I don't have a problem in local, but I get a lot of errors when I use it in my hosting provider. it's hosting providers problem?

i dont know what is problem

Comment: Have you tried adding an await to your interaction.deferReply?

Comment: yes, but I don't think it worked well. @Dan

Comment: I realized that I could solve the "has not been sent or delayed" error by adding await.

Comment: so how can i solve unknown interaction error? @Dan